# sublime text select first in each line

Tags: sublimetext2

In Vim there's a really nice feature to find/replace the first occurrence in each line. This is afaik actually the default behavior.
How can I obtain the same behavior in sublime text?

I need to be able to mark/find the FIRST (and the first only!) character, e.g. '=', in each line, so that I easily can mark/copy/cut what's before and what's after that specific character. Mind you, there might be many of this specific character in each line.

Concrete example:

I have a long list of java properties in the form:

```
my.property.link1=<a href="asdfs">Link 1</a>
my.property.link22=<a href="asdfs">Link 22</a>
my.property.link333=<a href="asdfs">Link 333</a>
my.property.link4444=<a href="asdfs">Link 4444</a>
```

I want to mark the first "=" in each line, to be able to select all the preceding text (indifferent from the amount of text preceding the "=") to cut or copy the text. The paste-result of such action would be:

```
my.property.link1
my.property.link22
my.property.link333
my.property.link4444
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Supposing you have the following text:

```
my.property.link1=<a href="asdfs">Link 1</a>
my.property.link22=<a href="asdfs">Link 22</a>
my.property.link333=<a href="asdfs">Link 333</a>
my.property.link4444=<a href="asdfs">Link 4444</a>
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (or click Find->Find)

Enable regular expressions

Type in the search field: `^.*?(?==)`

Preess <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or click Find All)

Now all the text before `=` is selected, you just need to copy it.

Comment: Thanks for this! This solved me a bunch of time now in sublime!

Answer (score 40):

I actually wrote a sublime plugin called SelectUntil that addresses this exact problem: https://github.com/xavi-/sublime-selectuntil

Once it's install you can do the following

- Select all the line you'd like edit or partially copy
- Press <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> -- this gives each line it's own cursor.
- Bring each cursor to the beginning of it's line by pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> if you're using OSX
- Press <kbd>Ctrl/Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to activate SelectUntil
- Tell SelectUntil to select until the equals sign by typing <kbd>=</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to deselect the equals sign
- At this point the names of all the properties should be selected so you can copy/paste as you'd like

The experience should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: That's really a helpful tool

Comment: I concur, I wish I had the patience (or serendipity) to write plugins for sublime each time I encounter a situation where they would be useful.

Answer (score 8):

[CTRL + A] ; [CTRL + Shift + L] ; [Home]

make a AutoItInputMacro.exe
Map that to [Home]
1 press button GG 
No rematch.

Comment: For anyone curious, this is what Ctrl + Shift + L (Splitting the Selection into Lines) does: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html

Answer (score 3):

Tried this and it seems to work:

Regex find using ^(.*)(STRING_TO_MATCH)

\1 will give all the stuff before your match, \2 gives the match itself.

You could also use ^(.*)(STRING_TO_MATCH)(.*) and then \3 would be everything after.

Edit - if you're looking to select and copy, I tried this: `^[^CHAR]*`

This will find everything from the beginning of the line up to and not including your character.  From there you can right click to copy.  I haven't found a keystroke sequence to do it since the find panel has focus, maybe you can figure it out.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. Bare in mind, that I need to able to make a selection after the find...

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you have the following text:

```
AAAABBBCCCC
ABC
BBBAAACCC
ABCABCABC
```

..and you want to replace every first occurrence of A in each line by X:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (or click Find->Replace)

Find what: `A(.*)`

Replace With: `X\1`

Then click in replace all.

Comment: That would end up with:
`X
X
BBBX
X`

You probably want Replace With: X\1

Comment: This works - when you replace certain text. However, I want to mark all the text preceding the match, to be able to copy/paste into another document...

Comment: @Hoof OK, I've just posted another answer that I think can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select all with `Ctrl + A` then press `Ctrl + Shift + L` and finally go to "Selection-> Invert Selection" like the picture et Voila!:
[image: Invert Selection]

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you can use the command line `cc.gbc 1/=/` of ConyEdit (a plugin) to get the text before the first column of regex match.